# Counting clicks to external links with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Entry` model with `url` field, which contains link to external site.
In view I list these links, and now I'd like to start counting when someone clicks it, and keep this info in database. What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use google analytics to track outbound links: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920

If that is not an option you will need to add some javascript to your links make an ajax request to the server to increment the count before transferring the user to the new url. Something similar to this jquery code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var stored_ulr = $(this).attr('href');

  $.ajax({
   url: #your server url to increment count,
   data: #data you need to send,
   success: function() { window.location = stored_url; },
  });

 return false;
});
```

The above code is just a general outline. You will have to fill in the blanks and make it work for your needs.

Comment: I don't know why Google uses onclick parameter on links. Isn't it better to use Javascript to catch click on the link and call the google funkction?